# How to show that some equation does not have any solutions in $\mathbb Q_p^2$.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

1. Is it true that if an equation has solutions in $\mathbb Q^2$, it has a solution in $\mathbb Q_p^2$ for all primes $p$?
   For example, if $f(a, b) = a^2 - 2b^2$, the only solution of $f(a,b) = 0$ in $\mathbb Q^2$ is $(0,0)$. For $p\neq 2$, this gives a solution in $\mathbb Q_p^2$ using Hensel's lemma. However, for $p = 2$, Hensel's lemma fails. Does this mean that there is no solution of $f(a,b) = 0$ in $\mathbb Q_2^2$? I'm confused about this because there exists an embedding $\mathbb Q\hookrightarrow\mathbb Q_p$. Does this embedding not preserve equations?
2. How can we show that some equation does not have any solutions in $\mathbb Q_p^2$?

Comment: $(a,b)=(0,0)$ is a solution of $a^2-2b^2=0$ in $\Bbb{Q}_2^2$ as well. It is also true that it is the only solution in $\Bbb{Q}_2^2$. This is because when they are both non-zero $a^2$ is divisible by an even power of $2$ and $2b^2$ is divisible by an odd power of two. That's one of the available techniques. A more common one is to show that a solution could be assumed to be in $\Bbb{Z}_p^2$, when we can reduce it modulo (a power of) $p$.

Comment: Just a comment about your reasoning. Just because some theorem fails and so a particular proof does not work does **not** imply that the statement is false!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: What do you mean by that last technique?

Comment: @user21820: Yes, I was aware of that. I wondered whether for example every solution in $\mathbb Q_p^2$ could be obtained by using Hensel's lemma on some solution of $\mathbb Q^2$.

Comment: For example: The equation $x^2=5$ has no solution  $x\in\Bbb{Q}_2$. For clearly a solution $x$ would have to be an element of $\Bbb{Z}_2$. Then reducing modulo $8$ would show that $x^2\equiv5\pmod 8$ has a solution in
$\Bbb{Z}_2/8\Bbb{Z}_2\simeq \Bbb{Z}/8\Bbb{Z}$. The latter is easy to show to be impossible by testing all the eight elements of $\Bbb{Z}/8\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: The same argument shows that $a^2=5b^2$ has only the trivial solution in $\Bbb{Q}_2^2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you for your answer. This was exactly the kind of technique I was looking for.